# LAbel Control Top Border is Not Adjusting

Tags: css

I have a label control in tabel cell and with css on hover i have set the top border or red color.PRoblem is that the poistion of top border is showing distance bewtween border as like in my image attached with question

[image]

If You see then the red border is not like a square cornered and also showing a blank top space on top of it.I have much tried to remove this but i failed.Please anyone help me to make the border corners equal and also black space should like this second image.In short i want to make border like this image

[image]

My css code is bellow

```
#sddmCA div
{   position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #444444;
    border: 1px solid #959595;
    border-top-color:#464646;
    margin-top:1cm;
```

and label control code is here

```
<ul id="sddmCA">
<asp:Label ID="CA"   runat="server" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#CCCCCC" Style="margin-top:auto;" Height="100%" Text="Current Activities"         onmouseover="var b = ChangeColorCA();  hideshow(this);   this.style.cursor='pointer'; boldCA();    return b"                                     onmouseout="var b = mclosetime();   return b;" onclick="var a = mopen('m11'); this.style.background='#464646'; this.style.color='#FFFFFF'; this.style.borderBottomColor ='#464646'; this.style.borderRightColor ='#464646'; this.style.borderLeftColor ='#464646';  return a"  ></asp:Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either set a black border on the non-hovered state that is the same width as the hovered state, or use a box shadow (depending on which browsers you choose to support)

```
#sddmCA div /*removed non-question related code*/
{   
    border: 1px solid #959595;
    border-top-color:#000000;
}

#sddmCA div:hover
{   
    border: 1px solid #959595;
    border-top-color:#464646;
}
```

This will keep it in the same place as the border doesn't change its size when hovered.

Comment: This make no difference please tell anyother idead

Comment: Do you have a live example somewhere we can take a look at?

Comment: yes i have please visti here http://202.125.144.34:85/Index.aspx and tell me where is the mistake

Comment: Hover the mouse on The all Labels on Black area

Comment: scroll the css file to the end because related CSS class code is #sddmCA